# Web Application Auditing

Tags: .net, database, auditing, audit-trail, audit-tables

How can I audit a web application specifically database changes, when the application is connecting to the database as a system account?

I would like to use a simple database trigger to write to an audit table but I am unsure of how I would be able to add the user that is logged on instead of the account that is actually doing the work.

I have read a few articles on identity flow but I do not fully understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on MSSQL 2008, you should look into CDC (Change Data Capture):

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/

As exeshu mentions, tiggers/CDC won't audit who your web-app user was unless you have some audit columns on all your tables (createdBy, lastModifiedBy etc - populated on every insert/update), so maybe look into something like that.